# SQL: selecting from three tables

Tags: sql, join

If I have three tables, A/B/C, A is related to B and B is related to C, and I want to get information from A using information from C can I do the following? :

```
SELECT A.field 
FROM A, B, C
WHERE A.key = B.key and B.key2 = C.key2 and C.field = 'some_data';
```

I tried looking this up and I saw a lot of mention of "JOINS," but I'm not that experienced with SQL.  So I was wondering: would my solution logically work? and how is it different from a JOIN where you actually use the JOIN keyword?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works fine. However, it's preferable to use explicity join syntax:

```
SELECT A.field
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.key = B.key
JOIN C ON B.key2 = C.key2
WHERE C.field = 'some_data';
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should use a JOIN clause in this case.

Assuming this is Microsoft SQL Server your are using:

```
SELECT A.field 
FROM A
JOIN B on B.key = A.key
JOIN C on C.key2 = B.key2
AND C.field = 'some_data';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you did will work and that is actually what we call an "Equijoin."
However, if you work on a lot of tables it is more efficient to explicitly use join syntax as Barmar pointed out with regard to readability of code.